# Delete Row based on all columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm just beginning sql and would like to know how to delete a row based on all of its columns.
I have a table called `rebels` with columns `rebel_name`, `rebel_fleet`, and `rebel_skill`. I tried doing the following but no row was affected. What did I fail to include in my logic?

```
DELETE FROM rebels
WHERE rebel_name = 'Matar Sewtor'
AND rebel_fleet = 'Alliance'
AND rebel_skill = 'Pilot';
```

Comment: The statement is syntactically correct. Do you have a row with those values?

Comment: do you have record exist with above details?

Comment: Let me make sure there's no issue with the whitespace and yes this record exists with all of those attributes. Minor mistake with spacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing the right thing.  I suspect that you've made a simple spelling mistake in one of the fields, or there could be invisible trailing whitespace after one of the fields.

Comment: if the whitespace is an issue adding `RTRIM(LTRIM(rebel_skill))='XYZ'` for each column would help with that.

Comment: Thanks for that extra tip, that helped out a lot. @DanielE.

Comment: Better still, do that RTRIM(LTRIM(blahblah)) stuff as you write the record.  Better to do the trimming when you save it in the database rather than every time you're doing a lookup.